# browsing a file in the system using jsp

Tags: jsp

What I want is to run a python program in background when i choose a file from the system.That is when I click an "upload" button,I should get a "browse" button on the same page without changing anything else in that page. On clicking this "browse" button I should be able to select a file from my system. When I have chosen the file, the python program which I have already written and and stored in a file should run. No contents on the same page is modified or changed.

Comment: You should consider posting your relevant codes, analysis done on this and exact point/points where you are stuck. With current format it seems a low quality question.

Comment: Did you consider using `<input type="file" ... />`?